# Cannot Successfully Export And Then ReImport A View In MySql 5

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqlimport

When I export a database on my development PC, for import on my webhost, it contains the following line:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `vi_sr_videntity_0`
--

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `starrise`.`vi_sr_videntity_0` AS select `starrise`.`t_sr_u_identityfingerprint`.`c_r_Identity` AS `c_r_Identity`,`v_sr_videntityfingerprint`.`ID` AS `ID`,`v_sr_videntityfingerprint`.`FingerPrintID` AS `FingerPrintID`,`v_sr_videntityfingerprint`.`FingerPrintFingerPrint` AS `FingerPrintFingerPrint` from (`starrise`.`v_sr_videntityfingerprint` join `starrise`.`t_sr_u_identityfingerprint` on((`starrise`.`t_sr_u_identityfingerprint`.`c_id` = `v_sr_videntityfingerprint`.`ID`)));
```

Presumably because it says 'root'@'localhost', my hosted server won't accept the import.  I'm stuck and I don't know what to do.  Please help me know how to correctly transfer this database to my server.

Answer (score 0):

usually when you import the data in a web hosting server, you need to save your data to a sql format. Try to use phpwebadmin to export the data to a sql format and drop it into the database root in the hosted server.

*Assuming that you bought the mysql database service.

Make sure that your connection class in your codes is mapped to the location of the database server on the web.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No idea why but when you export from phpmyadmin it add a lot of extra data that in most cases is not required. For example you can remove the extra crap so that it is like this:

```
CREATE VIEW `vi_sr_videntity_0` AS select etc..........
```